# Flatten array of structs into several arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, flatten

Source code to understand the situation:

```
struct s { 
    int i; 
    float f 
};
const int cnt = 10;

s *source = new s[cnt];
/*... fill source ...*/

int *dest_i = new int[cnt];
float *dest_f = new float[cnt];

for (int x = 0; x < cnt; x++) {
    dest_i[x] = source[x].i;
    dest_f[x] = source[x].f;
}
```

So, here is the question: is there any faster method than iterate through array with loop?

Comment: Well, you have to copy each of them. How do you expect to do that without looping through one way or another?

Comment: I guess you could populate the flattened arrays as you are populating `s` itself, or maybe abandon `s` altogether.

Comment: @user315052, True, but from the question, I'm guessing you can't.

Comment: @chris Actually I'm looking for some kind of `memcpy` analog function with something like stride

Comment: @Yarg, You could use two `std::transform`s with quick lambdas if you don't mind looping twice.

Comment: @chris I've got a suspicion that it wont be faster, just a shugar

Comment: May I ask, why do you need it to be faster? With the current implementation, what is the time consumed in the loop? How much faster you want it to be?

Answer (score 1):

You could unroll your loop.  That's all I can think of off the top of my head.

It's a fairly pointless optimization to write yourself, the compiler can try to do it for you if you enable it (in gcc, compile with `--funroll-loops`)

Comment: Actually I'm looking for some kind of memcpy analog function with something like stride. Also size of array is not a const (made it in exaple only), so i'm not sure that it will be unrolled such way.